# Is it possible to add javascript syntax highlighting in the dart-editor?

Tags: javascript, dart, dart-editor

I have an javascript web-app which i will be porting to dart but in the dart editor there isn't any javascript syntax highlighting. I wanted to add the package since the editor is eclipse base ( i think )  but i couldn't find anyway to do this.

Is it at all possible to add javascript syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not planned https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=11239

It is suggested to use some of the other supported editors/IDEs like WebStorm/IntelliJ IDEA, Sublime Text, Eclipse Dart plugin, ... if you need such features.